# Lazy loading route angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I've been using Angular for a long time I know how routes work but I wanted to try something new for me using lazy loading, as you can see in my I'm trying to navigate from one point to another but something is wrong or maybe not possible.

thanks.

**ts.file**

```
this.router.navigate(['../delta']);
```

**app.routing.module.ts** // root file

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {
  path:delta,
  loadChildren: () => import('./delta/delta.module').then(m => m.DeltaModule.);
 }
]
```

is it possible to navigate like this?

Comment: May only be in the sample code, but you have a quote missing in your import statement.  Is that the problem?

Comment: @MikeHanson is juste sample code

Comment: I've been using angular for a long time, but never seen the ../ used in routes.  I suspect it won't match the delta route you defined.  Certainly the structure of the route looks fine to me if it is propertly formed with quotes and the dot at the end of m.DeltaModule is removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use that relative syntax, then you should do something like this:

```js
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,private router:Router){}

...

this.router.navigate(['../delta'], { relativeTo: this.route });
```